# JPA 2.1 Load extra data after object is loaded

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

With JPA, can I run a query after an object is loaded from the database?

For example, I have an entity that has this field:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "widget", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {})
    @OrderBy("happenedDate DESC")
    public List<Widget> getWidgets() {
        return widgets;
    }
```

This will **only** load all of the associated widgets.  What I really want are the first 20 in the result set with the order by the `happenedDate`.  Is there an annotation that can specify a method to run after my object is loaded from the DB so I can run a query and get limited results, something like:

```
@AfterDataLoaded
List<Widget> loadLast20WidgetsWidgets(){
    // Do query here
}
```

Does this annotation or pattern exist?

Comment: the fetch type of your `getWidgets` method is eager ... why don't you simply return the first 20 elements of this list in your `getLast20Widgets`method ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a combination of @EntityListener (class level) and  @PostLoad (method level) to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using the Hibernate specific, non JPA compliant `@Where` annotation which takes a native sql clause to limit the results loaded to an associated collection.

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#entity-hibspec-collection

How this query would look will depend on your database support for LIMIT, TOP etc.

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "widget", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {})
@OrderBy("happenedDate DESC")
@Where(clause = "id in (select top 20 id from table_name order by some_field desc)")
public List<Widget> getLast20Widgets() {
    return widgets;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this will work but I don't like the database specific SQL.  I'd like to keep this database agnostic and what I really wanted was Sanjeef's answer below

Answer (score 0):

There is no annotation to limit the no of records fetched. To accomplish that, you will have to run a JPA query, and that would be trivial.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I'm asking

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible since JPA/Hibernate has to manage entire collection's `transition` say from `persistent` to `removed` state.

You can anyways use below alternatives:

```
1.HQL or Native SQL

2.Criteria Query
```

Comment: Right, I know I can use those, the question is how to run them after the object loads.  Turns out the callback pattern is what I wanted.